# Facebook username too long in Pidgin

Tags: pidgin, facebook

Currently when chatting in pidgin my name that is displayed whenever I send a chat is too long and makes reading the chat difficult and sometimes confusing.

Is there a way to make the display name for all of the different protocols be something shorter like a nickname or something?

An example my facebook reads like this

```
(01:14:16 PM) username@chat.facebook.com/df747fe6_4BBB0493F66AE:
```

and I want it to look like this

```
(01:14:16 PM) username:
```

Comment: You can set an alias, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Pidgin -> Accounts -> Manage accounts -> Add -> Facebook.

Under "**User options -> Local alias:**" you can set your desired name.